# Is there a name for this discrete probability distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

What's the name for this probability distribution over the positive integers? (if it has a name)

P(n) = $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$ = $\frac{1} {n * (n+1)}$

Given a uniformly distributed real number r from 0 to 1, this is the distribution for $\lfloor\frac{1}{r}\rfloor$

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/does-this-distribution-have-a-name-or-what-is-a-stochastic-process-that-could-g

Answer (score 6):

It is the case $\rho=1$ of the [Yule-Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yule%E2%80%93Simon_distribution) distribution.